# Database schema compare options in Visual Studio 2013 - Abort Update Target

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, database-project, schema-compare

So I was comparing databases on visual studio schema compare.
Then I have pressed the update target button and it proceeded to updating the schema. Now I actually get a

**'The reverse engineering operation cannot continue because you do not have view definition permission'**.

I am aware of this error and why it is happening. However my question is how do I abort this operation? I believe there was no changes because the default option was set to

'**Block in case of possible data loss**'

So how do I abort this operation?

Comment: There's a Stop button on the toolbar in the Schema Compare window. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, but that is only during the process that you can stop it using the stop button. However, the Update process has gone through. Now my problem is every time I try to run the schema comparison to the same databases, I end up facing the same problem above.

Comment: If the update operation is already stopped, then what operation are you trying to abort?